# Difference between conditional survival and left truncation analysis for cancer patients?

Tags: survival, truncation, conditional

I am looking at cancer patient survival and want to know how long-term survival is after already having survived some time.

I am more familiar with conventional conditional survival, but have recently seen in SEER*Stat a function called "Left truncated life table session".

Would it be suitable to use left truncated life table analysis to interpret mortality after having survived a certain time period after diagnosis? Or is this a completely different approach?

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the data that you have. Left truncation would be for a situation where the date of diagnosis is the choice for `time = 0` and someone only entered the study some time after the date of diagnosis. If you have data on all patients starting with their dates of diagnosis, then those aren't left-truncated observations. So the answer depends on the data that you are analyzing.